# How to Store data in an array in Android from php http request

Tags: php, android

Here is my php code :

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
$response["title"]=$row['title'];
$response["url"]=$row['url'];
echo json_encode($response);
  }

?>
```

I want to store title and url in an array in android. 
title[], url[].

I tried searching for http requests but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: You should try harder ...

Comment: could you add more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should make some changes in .php, something like this:

```
$r=mysql_query("select * FROM links",$con);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
$cls[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($cls));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If you get some results when you run this script then the first step is done. Then we go to make some coding in Java.

This is part from one of my projects so don't just copy. It is needed to make some adjustments for your needs:

```
public Map<String, String> getTitlesUrls()
{
    Map<String,String> TitlesUrl = new HashMap<String,String>();



    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/10.0.0.2/yourscript.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("1: log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try
    {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("2: log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);           

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }

        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

        TitlesUrl.put("Title", String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Title")));
        TitlesUrl.put("URL", String.valueOf(json_data.getString("url")));


    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
            Log.e("3: log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return TitlesUrl;
}
```